# iOS 12.1 determining whether Bluetooth was switched off from top/bottom swipe menu vs. Settings

Tags: core-bluetooth, ios12, cbcentralmanager

It seems that when Bluetooth is powered off from the top/bottom swipe menu in iOS 12.1, the beacon ranging (and beacon detection) does not stop. The Bluetooth Central Manager will report `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`, but ranging continues and `didRangeBeacons:` is still getting called.

If the Bluetooth is switched off from Settings, ranging stops and beacons are not detected. However, the Central Manager still reports the same state `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`.

Is there a way to distinguish somehow whether the Bluetooth was switched off from the swipe menu or Settings app?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that to be honest, at least I don't know of a way. The Bluetooth state in Core Bluetooth is not really related to the state of the Core Location framework. I seem to recall that the whole reason why they changed the Swipe Menu toggle behavior was so that they could keep running the location services (along with Handoff, Apple Watch, AirPods, etc..) even when the user believes that he/she has turned bluetooth off. Very confusing in my opinion.

Comment: It's also misleading since "turning off" from the swipe menu doesn't actually turn off the bluetooth central, for example for ranging iBeacons, but it reports being `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`.